# How can I retrieve both ipv4 and ipV6 address of the client that makes request to a web page

Tags: c#, .net, ip, httprequest

How can I retrieve both ipv4 and ipV6 address of the client that makes request to a web page in C#?

Suppose the user request `pageA.aspx`, then what code should I use in the `Page_Load` event of that C# code-behind file to get this information?

Also I need client port number, server port number.

Comment: You can't. There is no 1-1 correspondence between IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If you're receiving communication across IPv4, you have *zero* IPv6 information to work with (and vice versa). And machines can have multiple addresses from both families (and let's ignore, for the time being, NAT). *What* are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, there is some issue with load balancer that  my web application is using. I just want to track the users .

Answer (score 0):

ipv6 is not yet fully replacing ipv4 , so you won't need that until all the devices and softwares (and of course .net framework) supports that, but if you are eager to be a step further ; you might write a function which converts ipv4 to ipv6 , for example try to clone this :
http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/ipv4-to-ipv6-converter.php

Comment: .net framework has supported IPv6 since at least [1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily(v=vs.71)). And your argument is "don't support IPv6 until *everyone else* does?" - how is that a good strategy? Finally, all your link gives is the mapping of IPv4 addresses within the IPv6 space - it doesn't give you any "real" IPv6 addresses assigned to the client

Comment: @Damien is correct. This does not answer OP's question. It is a comment, and an irrelevant comment at that. Adding helpful commentary is always welcome, but you should understand the important difference between an answer and a comment.